# Border-Radius & Box-Shadow Not Rendering Correctly

Tags: css

I am trying to use box-shadow, and border-radius together on a webpage, and it is showing a white image that fills in the space where the radius is. Think of it like when you safe a "transparent" image in photoshop with a drop shadow, to a jpg, or png-8 file.

Here is an image to show you what I mean.

(i cant post images yet, but here is the link)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpqYK.png

I am using this as my CSS

```
.whole
{
width: 1000px;
margin: 0 auto;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 2px #000000;
-mox-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 2px #000000;
box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 2px #000000; 
}


.top
{
height: 120px;
background-color: #1F1209;
margin-top: 50px;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
border-top-left-radius: 10px;
border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}

.footer
{
height: 250px;
background-color: #834C24;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright: 10px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 10px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}
```

So does anyone know if there is a way I can fix this? this is happening in Firefox and IE, by the way. I havent been able to check it out in other browsers though.

I would really prefer not to use a Photoshopped image... As CSS3 should definitely be used.

Any thoughts on this? I would greatly appreciate any help! :)

Thanks for your time folks!

Comment: can u do a jsfiddle for us to edit?

Comment: You need to show the matching HTML for your CSS.

Comment: You need to apply the border radius to the same element that has the box-shadow to get the effect you want.  In your case, `whole` should ALSO have the `border-radius` styles to achieve what you want.

Comment: Okay thanks I will try that out. I am using four different background-color's in four sectioned div's. So I just used the border-radius on the top and bottom. But I will work something out with your suggestions. Thanks! :)

Comment: So I applied the border-radius to the "whole" class. 
but I had to also keep the border-radius on the footer and top, or they wouldnt render correctly. 
That worked fine. 
But the only compliant I have is the "footer" div looks kind of messed up. 

As you can see in this image
http://i.imgur.com/3HSLG.png
there is a couple of whitish pixels showing, giving it a not-so-smooth look to it. 

Any thoughts on this one? Its not the biggest deal ever.. But it would be nice for it to flow, ya know?


thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little tip for you

Use this css3 for shortcuts instead of adding -left -right- top

```
border-radius:0px 0px 0px 0px;

<!-- [top left] [top right] [bottom right] [bottom left] -->
```

That would be easier if you do that.

And as for the box-shadow... I don't know why it is like that but I used this code and it works perfectly well.

```
box-shadow:0px 0px 10px black;

<!-- in case you don't know ...  [x coordinate] [y coordinate] [size of shadow] [color] -->
```

Well, I don't know if these codes will work on IE because I don't use IE browser and my computer will suddenly hang for a bit but... anyways.

I rewrite one of your class css code and I hope it work.

```
.footer
{
    height: 250px;
    background-color: #834C24;
    border-radius:10px 10px 10px 10px;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 50px black;
}
```

And I think even though you don't put -webkit- and -moz-, Mozilla and Chrome will read that. I hope it works on IE, too.

Anyways... that's it. Hope that'll work.

Comment: There is an even shorter shortcut for `border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px` - it is `border-radius: 10px`.

Comment: I'm just saying if he/she could type a different value on each sides. :)

Comment: Its looking good now (border-radius: 10px;) on "whole". (box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px #4F4F4F;) on whole. (border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;) on footer. & (border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;) on top. Looks slick.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a background colour associated with the container.

Comment: It's possible the colour is being inherited, just to rule it out try background:none; border:none;

Answer (score 0):

The border-radius property is supported in IE9+, Firefox 4+, Chrome, Safari 5+, and Opera, because it is CSS3 property. The syntax is:

```
border-radius: 1-4 length|% / 1-4 length|%;
```

**Example 1**

```
border-radius:2em;
```

is equivalent to:

```
border-top-left-radius:2em;
 border-top-right-radius:2em;
 border-bottom-right-radius:2em;
 border-bottom-left-radius:2em;
```

**Example 2**

```
border-radius: 2em 1em 4em / 0.5em 3em;
```

is equivalent to:

```
border-top-left-radius: 2em 0.5em;
 border-top-right-radius: 1em 3em;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 4em 0.5em;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 1em 3em;
```